# Drone Programming - Arducopter - Basic Python Scripting through Mission Planner

Tags: python

Can some with the knowledge of flying a drone programatically through mission planner help me out in the below?

I am a beginner in UAV. I am trying to do a very basic navigation of a quadcopter like takeoff, hover and land, through Mission Planner using Python.

I am having some difficulties on the very basics. I have been going through the sample codes and writing some scripts.

I wrote a basic script with just takeoff, hover and land. And I have faced some issues,
- The takeoff is in the reverse direction
- The takeoff is not vertically straight
- Altitude should be controlled. It should not go more than one meter. 
- Speed is high. How do I reduce it?

Also, 
When arming the motors, I saw in the sample code that we are setting the YAW to its maximum(2000) and bringing it back to neutral(1500). Why?
Below is my understanding of the RCs,
RC1 - ROLL
RC2- PITCH
RC3 - THROTTLE
RC4 - YAW
RC5 - For changing modes.

Can someone help me in resolving these issue? I have attached my sample code below.

Thank you!

```
import time

takeoff_throttle = 1700

def setup_rc():
    print("Set up all RCs to neutral")
    for chan in range(1,9):
        Script.SendRC(chan, 1500, False)
    SendRC(3, Script.GetParam('RC3_MIN'), True)
    Script.Sleep(5000)
    print("Done")

    return True

def arm_motors():
    "Arming motors"
    print('APM: ARMING MOTORS')  
    print("Setting mode to Stabilize")
    Script.ChangeMode("STABILIZE")  # STABILIZE MODE
    Script.SendRC(5, 1750, True)
    print("Done")
    print('Setting Throttle to minimum')
    Script.SendRC(3,1000,True)
    print("Done")
    print('Set Yaw')
    Script.SendRC(4,2000,True)
    print("Done")
    print('Waiting for Arming Motors')
    cs.messages.Clear()
    Script.WaitFor('ARMING MOTORS',20000)       #30000(30sec)
    print("Done")
    print('Reset Yaw')
    Script.SendRC(4,1500,True)
    print("Done")

    return True

def wait_altitude(alt_min, alt_max, timeout=30):
    climb_rate = 0
    previous_alt = 0
'''wait for a given altitude range'''
    tstart = time.time()
    print("Waiting for altitude between %u and %u" % (alt_min, alt_max))
    while time.time() < tstart + timeout:
    #m = mav.recv_match(type='VFR_HUD', blocking=True)
        climb_rate =  cs.alt - previous_alt
        previous_alt = cs.alt
    #print("Wait Altitude: Cur:%u, min_alt:%u, climb_rate: %u" % (cs.alt, alt_min , climb_rate))
        if cs.alt >= alt_min and cs.alt <= alt_max:
           print("Attained altitude:%u"%(cs.alt))
           print("Altitude OK")
           return True
    print("Failed to attain altitude range")
    return False

def takeoff(alt_min=0.5):
   print("Entered takeoff")
   print("About to takeoff")
   failed_status = False

   print("Make sure we are in stabilise mode")
   Script.ChangeMode("STABILIZE")
   Script.SendRC(5, 1750, True)
   print("Done")
   print("Increase the throttle")
   Script.SendRC(3, takeoff_throttle, True)

   print("Processing altitude control")

   found_alt = False

   if (cs.alt < alt_min):
        found_alt = wait_altitude(alt_min, alt_min + 0.5)

#Now we have our altitude we want to hold it

if found_alt:
    Script.ChangeMode("AltHold")
    Script.SendRC(5, 1000, True)

    print("Set the throttle between 40-60% to hold altitude")
    Script.SendRC(3, 1450, True)

    print("Takeoff complete")
else:
    print("Takeoff failed to reach adequate height")
    print("Initiate error control procedure")

    failed_status = True

return failed_status

def hover(hover_throttle = 1500):
    print("Entering Hover mode")
    print("Setting hover throttle")
    Script.SendRC(3, hover_throttle, True)
    print("Done")
    print("Hovering for 3 seconds")
    Script.Sleep(3000)
    print("Hover Complete")


def land():
'''land the quad'''
    print("STARTING LANDING")
    print("Changing Mode to LAND")
    Script.ChangeMode("LAND") # land mode
    Script.SendRC(5, 1300, True)
    print("Done")
    Script.WaitFor('LAND', 5000)
    print("Entered Landing Mode")
    ret = wait_altitude(-5, 1)
    print("LANDING: ok= %s" % ret)
    print("Landing complete")
    return ret

def disarm_motors():
'''disarm motors'''
    print("Disarming motors")
    print("Change mode to stabilize")
    Script.ChangeMode("STABILIZE") # stabilize mode
    print("Done")
    Script.WaitFor('STABILIZE', 5000)
    Script.SendRC(3, 1000, True)
    Script.SendRC(4, 1000, True)
    Script.WaitFor('DISARMING MOTORS',15000)
    Script.SendRC(4, 1500, True)
    #mav.motors_disarmed_wait()
    print("MOTORS DISARMED OK")
    return True

'''Main'''
 setup_rc()
 while cs.lat == 0:
    print 'Waiting for GPS'
    Script.Sleep(1000)
 print 'Got GPS'
 arm_motors()
 takeoff()
 land()
 disarm_motors()
 setup_rc()
```

Comment: If I had to guess - changing yaw to max & resetting probably helps zero it out from whatever it may have been before.

Comment: Just a note: in `takeoff()` in the lines starting at `Script.SendRC(5, 1750, True)`, it looks like you start with a higher throttle (1750) and then reduce it (1700) for take off, contrary to what your print statement says.